# Typescript keep type information mapping over object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object containing functions, which i have to wrap to use their return values, without changing their signature and while keeping type information.

```js
// a object containing functions
const functions = { foo, bar, baz }

// example wrapper
const doSomething: (result: any) => void;

// wrapper function for each function
function wrapper<P extends any[]>(fn: (...params: P) => any) {
    return (...params: P) => doSomething(fn(...params));
}

// the wrap function, which needs type information
function wrap(functions) {
    const wrapped = {};

    for (const key in functions) {
        wrapped[key] = wrapper(functions[key]);
    }

    return wrapped;
}

const wrapped = wrap(functions);

// get type information for wrapped and its functions here
```

Is it possible to keep type information (list of functions and their parameters) while wrapping the functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript won't infer this higher-order type operation for you; you'll have to annotate and assert in some places.  Inspecting the type of `wrapper` shows

```
/* function wrapper<P extends any[]>(fn: (...params: P) => any): (...params: P) => void */
```

so it returns a function whose parameters are the same as the input function, but which returns `void`.  In this case I'd write `wrap()` like:

```
function wrap<T extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any) => any>>(functions: T) {
    const wrapped = {} as { [K in keyof T]: (...p: Parameters<T[K]>) => void };
    for (const key in functions) {
        wrapped[key] = wrapper(functions[key]);
    }
    return wrapped;
}
```

The `functions` argument is of generic type `T` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to an object type whose properties are functions.  And the return `wrapped` is [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to be of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which has the same property names as `T`, and whose value function types are the same as the corresponding property of `T` but where the return type has been changed to `void`.  This uses the [`Parameters` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) to say that the output functions take the same parameters as the input functions.

I like to have complete examples when I write code for Stack Overflow, so here's the definitions I'm using:

```
const functions = {
    foo: (x: string) => x.length,
    bar: (x: number) => x.toFixed(2),
    baz: (x: boolean, y: boolean) => x && y;
}

const doSomething = (result: any) => { console.log(result) };
```

And then when I call `wrap()` we get the following behavior:

```
const wrapped = wrap(functions);
wrapped.foo("hey"); // 3
wrapped.bar(Math.PI); // 3.14
wrapped.baz(true, false); // false
```

If I try something wrong, the compiler complains:

```
wrapped.foo(true); // error! boolean is not a string
wrapped.foo("string", false); // error! expected 1 argument, got 2
```

Looks like what you want, I think.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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-dpHlNXRA28bbriiwWRyCwYq9v68bKK12A82Rj3thhh4R53wSyBqAAiMTGne4mB9GAAZiIG4UjGoAFl5OI+EcAJJHk+nvgARgALBepxY+E41BQIwCBCN4cDyAIEBCK+-QQVBQiyhuW5ASBMFRMe-TaIwpYAIRuPUQSzKgmBgCAsDyDATC5L+LbmJu5C7tRbA7uBkHQbBCyMDhjD4UItDjCgFgwB+DKMKwGgiFA3isORMBWEAA)

Comment: Thank you for the fast help

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [jcalz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64265266/8678740) I made an more generic function objects mapper.

It wraps every function in the object with a given function, without changing the objects type signature.

```js
function mapFunctionsObj<T extends Record<keyof T, (...p: any[]) => any>>(
    fn: <X>(result: X) => X,
    functions: T
) {
    const mapped = {} as any;
    for (const key in functions) {
        mapped[key] = (...params) => fn(functions[key](...params));
    }
    return mapped as { [K in keyof T]: (...p: Parameters<T[K]>) => ReturnType<T[K]> };
}
```

Please read the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64265266/8678740) to get some explanation on the typings.